# How to move/resize window by tapping/dragging on the touchpad on 14.04?

Tags: dell, touchpad, 14.04, multi-touch

I have a Dell XPS 13 Developers Edition that came with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed. In 12.04, I was able to move and resize windows by tapping/dragging on the touchpad with three fingers.

Yesterday, I upgraded my laptop to 14.04 and this feature is not available anymore. Is it possible to get it back? Two-finger scrolling still works in 14.04.